# Grouping data in R by presence of string within lists of strings

Tags: r, list, dplyr, grouping

I have a number of variables to group on, some are "normal" grouping variables (i.e. numeric/character strings) and some of which are lists of strings. What I want to do is determine a group based on matches between the "normal" variables & the presence of a match between any string within these lists.

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(cod=c(1:5,1:5,3))
dat$lst <- c(list(c("a","a"),c("b"),c("x","x"),c("r","r"),c("t","t"),c("a"),c("e"),c("f","x"),c("e","q"),c("t"),c("f","f")))
dat <- dat %>% arrange(cod)

#Data
cod lst
1 a, a
1    a
2    b
2    e
3 x, x
3 f, x
3 f, f
4 r, r
4 e, q
5 t, t
5    t
```

So where `lst` contains a string that is present in several of the same `cod`s I want to create a group, like this:

```
# Desired output
cod lst grp
1 a, a   1
1    a   1  
2    b   2
2    e   3
3 x, x   4
3 f, x   4
3 f, f   4
4 r, r   5
4 e, q   6 
5 t, t   7
5    t   7
```

In `grp` 4, all three observations should be linked as there are common list items shared between all three (i.e. one observation has a `lst` value of `c(f,x)` which links `c(f,f)` and `c(x,x)` within the `cod` group 3)

I tried to just create a logical TRUE/FALSE column that would show if some `cod`s should be grouped via:

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(cod) %>%
  mutate(grp = ifelse((lst %in% lst),TRUE,FALSE))
```

As well as via:

```
for (i in 1:dim(dat)[1]) {
     if (all(any(dat$cod[i] %in% dat$cod) & any(dat$lst[[i]] %in% unlist(dat$list[-i])))) {
         dat$grp[i] <- TRUE
       } else {
           dat$grp[i] <- FALSE
         }
 }
```

But nothing has been able to isolate unique groups so far. Any help greatly appreciated!!!! Thanks!

Comment: If `list` contained `c("f", "f")`, `c("x", "x")`,  and `c("f", "x")`, then how would you decide where to put `c("f", "x")`? You have not specified what you want unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks for raising this point Mikael. I had not thought of this as I do not imagine with a cod grouping that this would occur. However, if it did I would want to link all observations in the same group.

Comment: I have edited to clarify